# Vaadin color picker avoid popup

Tags: vaadin7, color-picker

We are using `Vaadin 7` color picker in our project. `Vaadin` color picker opens up in a new popup window by default.

How can I avoid that popup and to display the color selection area with in my vertical layout?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
ColorPickerPopup colorPickerPopup = new ColorPickerPopup(new Color(123, 131, 132));
mainLayout.addComponent(colorPickerPopup.getContent());
```

But the component contains also 2 buttons Ok can Cancel.
If you want to remove these 2 buttons:

```
VerticalLayout content = (VerticalLayout) colorPickerPopup.getContent();
content.removeComponent(content.getComponent(3));
mainLayout.addComponent(content);
```